# Ciclo while no termina nunca y no me imprime el resultado generado en cada iteración

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy nuevo en Python y tengo que resolver este ejercicio:

> Elaborar un programa para la función checador que calcule y regrese el REGISTRO_TIEMPO_DIARIO_LABORADO de un trabajador en un día a partir de los parametros TIEMPO_DE_ENTRADA Y TIEMPO_DE_SALIDA
>
> Suponga que el que pago por hora trabajada es de 12, elabore otro programa que utilice el anterior para calcular el tiempo laborado de una quincena para 20 trabajadores y que escriba una lista con el TIEMPO_QUINCENAL_LABORADO y su PAGO_DE_NOMINA correspondiente

Como soy nuevo en Python y mi profesor quiere que hagamos el ejercicio pero no nos ha enseñado nada, si no que el quiere que investiguemos por nuestra cuenta, solo pude llegar a pensar en esto:

```
hora_de_llegada=int(input("ingrese horario de entrada:"))   
hora_de_salida=int(input("ingrese horario de salida"))
horas_laboradas= hora_de_salida - hora_de_llegada

print ("las horas que tabajo son :"+str(horas_laboradas))

n=0
m=n+1

while (n!=20):
    hora_de_llegada=int(input("ingrese horario de entrada:"))
    hora_de_salida=int(input("ingrese horario de salida"))
    horas_laboradas= hora_de_salida - hora_de_llegada
print ("las horas que tabajo son :"+str(horas_laboradas))
```

El problema es que al correrlo solo me indica la hora laborada de los 2 primeros datos que inserto, después sigo insertando los datos pero ya no devuelve la hora laborada y el ciclo no termina nunca.

La versión de Python que ocupo es 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tenias en el contador del ciclo while, debe estar dentro del ciclo.

```
contador = 0 #esta variable es un contador para el ciclo while

#funciones


def ingreso_de_horas(): #esta es la funcion que calcula la hora de entrada y la hora de salida
    hora_de_llegada = int(input("Ingrese su horario de entrada: ")) #hora de llegada  
    hora_de_salida = int(input("Ingrese su horario de salida: ")) #hora de salida
    horas_laboradas = hora_de_salida - hora_de_llegada #calculo de horas laboradas
    print("*" * 50) #separador
    print("las horas que tabajo son: {}".format(horas_laboradas)) #concatenar texto y variables
    print("\n") #salto de linea

programa

while contador != 5: #mientras el contador no sea igual a 5 ejecutará lo siguiente
    ingreso_de_horas() #se ejecuta la funcion que calcula las horas trabajadas
    contador = contador + 1 #en cada vuelta se suma un 1 hasta llegar a 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos problemas en el código:

- El ciclo `while` tal y como está es un **ciclo infinito** porque **la variable de control**  `n` es declarada e inicializada a 0 antes de iniciarlo, pero **nunca es modificado su valor** después. Esto hace que la condición de salida del `n != 20` nunca se cumpla al ser `n` siempre 0 y el ciclo seguirá iterando por siempre jamás hasta que no fuerces la terminación del proceso. Para que funcione correctamente debes sumarle uno a la variable de control `n` en cada iteración del ciclo.
- Solo te imprime los dos primeros datos porque son los que capturas antes del `while`, como tienes el último `print` fuera del ciclo este solo imprimirá una vez cuando se termine el ciclo. Como tu ciclo es infinito nunca te imprimirá nada. Si el ciclo no fuera infinito solo imprimiría solo el resultado de la última iteración del mismo. Para que retorne los datos en cada vuelta del ciclo el `print` debe estar dentro del `while`.

Para capturar 20 pares de datos y por cada uno retornar la diferencia sería simplemente:

```
n = 0
while (n != 20):
    hora_de_llegada = int(input("ingrese horario de entrada: "))
    hora_de_salida = int(input("ingrese horario de salida: "))
    horas_laboradas= hora_de_salida - hora_de_llegada
    print("Las horas que trabajó son: ", horas_laboradas)
    n = n + 1
```

No obstante, es preferible usar un `for` siempre que el número de iteraciones sea conocido antes del mismo, es más simple y eficiente:

```
for _ in range(20):
    hora_de_llegada = int(input("ingrese horario de entrada: "))
    hora_de_salida = int(input("ingrese horario de salida: "))
    horas_laboradas= hora_de_salida - hora_de_llegada
    print("Las horas que trabajó son: ", horas_laboradas)
```

Comment: gracias ya tendria el codigo para ver cuanto se les pagaria por dia, pero tengo otra duda como podria hacer para que reinicie el programa sin que tenga que cerrarlo y correrlo otra vez?

Comment: @lalohernandez puedes usar otro ciclo que englobe al código que quieras reiniciar, usar funciones, etc. Depende de como sea tu código y de que quieras hacer.